# wxWidgets: SetHint() on multiline wxTextCtrl and process TAB

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, wxtextctrl

Like the title says, is there any way to set hint on a wxTextCtrl that is a multi line text?. I already tried but didn't work. Should I do it manually?

Edit: I wanna add this: How can I make the wxTextCtrl lose his focus when TAB key is pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints for multiline text controls are only supported in the latest master and only under some platforms, see [this commit](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/commit/e8374a47fe277b01c93b07ab00d39b2cd294ea0a) for more details.